# idapython: how to reset pointer type for variables

Tags: ida, idapython, hexrays

I am using IDA Pro 7.6 on win32 x86 binaries.

I'm trying to use the ida_hexrays interface to decompile subroutines. I want all of the local variables and arguments of the subroutine to have integral types, no pointer types. I made this function to do all the processing for me

```
import ida_hexrays
import ida_typeinf as ida_type
import ida_lines

def decompile_function( function_location ):
    decompile_handle = ida_hexrays.decompile( function_location, flags = ida_hexrays.DECOMP_NO_CACHE )

    for local_variable in decompile_handle.lvars:
        type_info = local_variable.type()

        try:    
            if ida_type.is_type_ptr( type_info.get_decltype() ):
                pointed_object = type_info.get_pointed_object()

                if ida_type.is_type_integral( pointed_object.get_decltype() ):
                    local_variable.set_lvar_type( type_info.get_pointed_object() )      
        except:
            pass

    decompile_handle.refresh_func_ctext()

    pseudo_code = decompile_handle.get_pseudocode()
    decompile_result = ""

    for code_line in pseudo_code:
        decompile_result = decompile_result + ida_lines.tag_remove( code_line.line ) + "\n";

    return decompile_result
```

When I decompile, I can see in the variable list that all of the variables are integral types

```
unsigned __int8 v7; // al
int v10; // eax
unsigned int v11; // esi
const char v12; // cl
_DWORD v13; // eax

v13 = (_DWORD *)v11;
```

However, as you may notice above, `v13 = (_DWORD *)v11` v13 is improperly being set as a pointer. As it turns out, none of the code except the variable declarations gets changed. This happens for every subroutine that I try to decompile with this.

But when I right-click and use reset pointer value, the code changes and it would look like `v13 = v11;`. What is the issue with my code, or is IDAPython/IDAHexrays to blame? How do I make it actually reset the pointer value and not just in the declaration list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function, `lvar_t::set_lvar_type`, is accompanied by the following comment:

```
  /// Note: this function does not modify the idb, only the lvar instance
  /// in the memory. For permanent changes see modify_user_lvars()
```

Instead of calling `set_lvar_type`, you're going to want something like this instead:

```
def ChangeVariableType(func_ea, lvar, tif):
    lsi = ida_hexrays.lvar_saved_info_t()
    lsi.ll = lvar
    lsi.type = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t(tif)
    if not ida_hexrays.modify_user_lvar_info(func_ea, ida_hexrays.MLI_TYPE, lsi):
        print("[E] Could not modify lvar type for %s" % lvar.name)
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I use this code it doesn't seem to make any changes to the decompiled output at all?

Here is my new code [https://pastebin.com/KqFfkpV1](https://pastebin.com/KqFfkpV1)

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. In short, you're going to need to decompile the function again. If you had a `vdui_t` object instead of a `cfunc_t` object, you could call `vdui_t::refresh_view` with the `bool` parameter set to `True`. Alternatively, you could invoke `decompile` again after the loop that modifies the variable types.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I end up doing something like this. But when I look at the output, still nothing at all has changed. All the types remain the exact same as they were before in the decompiled output. Here is a link to the new code [https://pastebin.com/wYh8BQU6](https://pastebin.com/wYh8BQU6)

Comment: Edit: I realized that _DWORD is an unacceptable integral type, and the decompiler just doesn't seem to agree with it. I changed the type to "int", and voila it worked and all the types persisted throughout the whole code.